# "Частично" или "отчасти"?

Tags: выбор-слов

Здравствуйте. Можно ли написать "частично согласиться"? Или лучше "отчасти согласиться"?

Answer (score 4):

Лучший вариант: **отчасти согласиться**.

Из словаря: **ЧАСТИЧНО**, нареч. Ч. возместить затраты. Ч. выполнить работу. Ч. ответить на вопрос. **ОТЧАСТИ**, нареч. Не вполне, в некоторой степени; частично. Разговор этот о. успокоил мать. **Прав только о. кто-л.** О. успокоить кого-л. Предсказание о. сбылось.

Хотя наречия здесь представлены как синонимы, их сочетаемость с другими словами не всегда совпадает. **К теме согласия** можно отнести следующие сочетания: **согласен вполне, не вполне,  отчасти**, в Нацкорпусе также даны примеры с наречием "отчасти":

То есть я был с ним **отчасти согласен**. [Александр Рекемчук. Мальчики // «Юность», 1970]. **Отчасти согласен** с этим: для подобного прорыва требовались, конечно, некоторые фантазия и смелость. [Борис Грищенко. Посторонний в Кремле (2004)]. С этим я **согласен отчасти**. [Сергей Шаповал. (2003) // «Независимая газета», 2003.04.09]

Comment: Спасибо. А можно написать "частично простить"? Не в количественном смысле (вроде "частично простить долг"), а, например, "частично простить автору его предрассудок"?